# Node.js and socket.io initialization setInterval()

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have an event on server that is triggered when the client sends a message:

```
socket.on('message', function(data){
        message.push(data);
});
```

And now when all clients send a message, I want to wait for 3 seconds and then call a function.

I tried with Interval:

```
var index=0;
var timer;


socket.on('message', function(data){
    message.push(data);
    if (index==0) //only once
       timer = setInterval(call(), 3000);
    index++;
});

function call(){
     io.sockets.emit("confirmation", {status: "All messages are delivered"});
     clearInterval(timer); // Clear interval
}
```

The problem is that the function call() call immediately and not after 3 seconds.
The second problem is that clearInterval(timer) in function call, does not work because the function call repeats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. I solve the problem.
The problem was that I wanted to create a `setInterval()` within `io.on("connection", function(socket){}`, but it makes for each client separately. I did not want this.
Now I put before and it works:

```
var index=0;
var timer;
var check=false;

timer = setInterval(function(){fcall()}, 3000);

function fcall(){
   if(check)
   {
       io.sockets.emit("confirmation", {status: "All messages are delivered"});
       clearInterval(timer); // Clear interval
       timer=0;
   }
}

io.on("connection", function(socket){

   socket.on('message', function(data){
     message.push(data);
     if (index==0) //only once
       check = true;
     index++;
   });

}
```

Comment: Please see my answer above, it will help you: `setInterval(function(){fcall()}, 3000);` can be simplified to `setInterval(fcall, 3000);`

Answer (score 2):

If you only want this to occur once, you should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.
This will save you from needing to clear the interval later, and makes the code more explicit that you want it to happen exactly once, 3 seconds from "now."

In addition "(...)" at the end of a function name causes it to be called immediately. You want to pass the function "call" as a parameter, not cause it to be called immediately.

I would also recommend you name the function something other than `call`, as this is already a name of a standard function in Javascript, and therefore can get confusing quickly. Even calling it `callback` would reduce confusion.

So, what you're looking for is something like this:

`setTimeout(callback,3000);`

in place of this

`setInterval(call(), 3000);`

Answer (score 0):

You are making a call to the function from setInterval function.

It should be`timer = setInterval(call, 3000);` and not <strike>timer = setInterval(call(), 3000);</strike>